# Regla de validación opcional en Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, validación

¿Cómo hacer opcional una regla de validación en Codeigniter utilizando el archivo de configuración para ello?

Creando el archivo `form_validation.php` dentro de la carpeta `/config` en Codeigniter podemos agrupar todas las reglas que utilizamos de cualquier controlador.

Desde el mismo controlador, es muy sencillo hacer una regla opcional encapsulándola dentro de un condicional `if`, pero usando el archivo no sé cómo realizar lo mismo.

Archivo `form_validation.php`:

```
<?php
    $config = array(
    'company' => array(
        array(
            'field' => 'name',
            'label' => lang('companies_name'),
            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[255]',
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'contact_name',
            'label' => lang('companies_contact_name'),
            'rules' => 'trim|requried|max_length[191]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'email',
            'label' => lang('companies_email'),
            'rules' => $this->CI->input->post('company_id') > 0? 'trim|max_length[100]|valid_email|callback_is_unique_email[' . $this->CI->input->post('company_id') . ']' : 'trim|required|max_length[100]|valid_email|callback_is_unique_email'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'phone',
            'label' => lang('companies_phone'),
            'rules' => 'trim|max_length[20]'
        ),
        array(
            'field' => 'ext',
            'label' => lang('companies_phone_ext'),
            'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[20]'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Aquí, la regla `phone_ext`, debería de ser la opcional. Solo en el caso de `phone` tenga un valor.

Comment: Si dices que se trata de un campo que puede tener o no tener valor entonces con quitarle a tu regla el `required` lo tendrías.

Comment: Si quito el `required` no podré requerirla cuando el campo `phone`, se haya rellenado. Dicho de otro modo, si hay teléfono, debe de haber extensión, no puede ser nulo.